# PocessBuilder execute glassfish command

Tags: java, linux, cmd, terminal, glassfish

I try to get the list of instances of my cluster, for that i use ProcessBuilder to execute a command :

```
asadmin list-instances --long=true
```

when i execute this command from java in **windows** it work fine, but when i deploy my application in a real server in Linux i get an exception:

> Exception = java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/sh -c
>   'asadmin list-instances --long=true'": error=2, Aucun fichier ou
>   dossier de ce type

And when i execute this command directly in the server it work fine?
i really can't understand what is the problem

Here is my Java code:

```
public String executerCommande() {
    String line, line2 = "";
    try {
        //Windows command
        //ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
        //I use this with quots and without quotes
        //ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh -c asadmin list-instances --long=true");
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh -c 'asadmin list-instances --long=true'");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            line2 += r.readLine() + "\n";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception = " + e);
    }
    return line2;
}
```

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Runtime might help

```
    try {
         String command = "asadmin list-instances --long=true";
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
         for (String s = br.readLine(); s != null; s = br.readLine()) {
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
         }
         br.close();
         p.waitFor();
         System.out.println("command executed exited: " + p.exitValue());
         p.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" + e);
    }
```

Comment: I test this in windows and it not work: `Exceptionjava.io.IOException: Cannot run program "asadmin": CreateProcess error=2, Le fichier spécifié est introuvable`

Comment: its give me this error: `Exceptionjava.io.IOException: Cannot run program "asadmin": error=2, Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type`